# In the RMS bandwidth equation, why do we have the energy of the signal in the denominator?

Tags: lowpass-filter, bandwidth, signal-energy, rms

In the following equation:
$$B_{\rm rms}^2 = \frac{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2\lvert G(f)\rvert^2df}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert G(f)\rvert^2df}.$$

It is not clear why do we divide the RMS of the signal by its energy, I tried looking for answers in several books but did not find any explination.

Comment: To normalize it.  Otherwise bandwidth will be dependent on the energy of the $g(t)$.  It's like that for any average or mean.

You gotta ***thing*** that is measured in units of ***fargs***.  What is the mean-square *farg* of all of the *things*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|G(f)|^2$ is a nonnegative function of $f$. Another nonnegative function that might be familiar to you is a *probability density function* (pdf). Is $|G(f)|^2$ a pdf? Not necessarily because the area under the $|G(f)|^2$ curve is not necessarily equal to $1$.  Well, the area under the $|G(f)|^2$ curve is
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert G(f)\rvert^2 \,\mathrm df$$
and so
$$\frac{|G(f)|^2}{\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert G(f)\rvert^2 \,\mathrm df}$$
is indeed a valid pdf of some random variable $X$. (It is also the energy special density of a *unit*-energy signal). Then, what is $E[X^2]$?  it is given by
\begin{align}E[X^2] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2\cdot \left[\frac{|G(f)|^2}{\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert G(f)\rvert^2 \,\mathrm df}\right] \,\mathrm df\\
&= \frac{\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2{|G(f)|^2}\,\mathrm df}{\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lvert G(f)\rvert^2 \,\mathrm df}\\
&= B_{\text{rms}}^2~~!!
\end{align}
If we were to *amplify* the signal by a factor ot $2$, say, then its RMS bandwidth will not change, but its energy spectral density will increase. Thus, *normalizing* the energy spectral density to be that of a unit-energy signal gives us $B_{\text{rms}}^2$.